# TreeWidget Parent Child Check

Tags: qt, qt4

I want to check whether a particular row in tree widget have parent and child.
When i give single click on a row it have to check for parent and child.
Can some one give some idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Open Qt Assistant
- Look for QTreeWidget
- Go to Signals section and see which signal you really need - I assume `itemClicked()` or `itemActivated()` in you case
- Examine what info you get from the chosen signal - a QTreeWidgetItem may be?
- Go to QThreeWIdgetItem in Qt Assistant
- Look some functions that can help you - may be `childCount()` and `parent()` ?

Hope this helps

Comment: childCount i implemented but parent is returning QTreeWidgetItem and if no parent then what QTreeWidgetItem will hold